# Swift reflections - get vars used in a method

Tags: swift, reflection

Is there a way in swift to get all vars being used within a method?

I have read about Mirror class, but didn't manage to produce the wanted code.

```
class A {
     var prop1: Any
     var prop2: Any
     var propB: B
     init() {
         propB = B() {
              ................
              ...self.prop1...
              ................
              ...someGlobal...
              ................
         }
     }
}
class B {
    init(compution: @escaping () -> Any) {
        var usedVars : [Any] = compution.getUsedVars()
        // now usedVars contains [a.prop1&, someGlobal&]
    }
}

var a = A()
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.